# Union all when one query is missing a column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is similar to the code I use:

```
SELECT id, col1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col2 FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col3 FROM table3
...
```

For example `col2` in `table2` does not exist, how to make this query work and not to query for columns that do not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NULL` or any other value and alias it to match column list defintion:

```
SELECT id, col1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, NULL AS col2 FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col3 FROM table3
```